# iPhone: How to keep timer awake when iPhone is locked?

Tags: iphone, nstimer

I have just noticed that my timer callback function stops firing when iPhone screen gets locked. Is there anyway to tell iPhone to keep awake my timer? Any other way to do things periodically when iPhone is locked?

I am using NSTimer from viewDidLoad to schedule timer call back function every second.

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector: @selector(levelTimerCallback) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

Thanks.

Comment: The message signature is wrong.

Comment: @Radek If the signature was wrong it wouldn't compile or run correctly in the foreground.

Comment: It would compile due to Objective-C's dynamic binding. The correct message signature would be `levelTimerCallback:` and not `levelTimerCallback`.

Comment: @Radek S you're wrong. It can be levelTimerCallback

Comment: @Max [Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html). It says: "The message to send to target when the timer fires. The selector must have the following signature: `- (void)timerFireMethod:(NSTimer*)theTimer`"

Comment: @Radek S It should, if you want to get the caller (timer). But if there is no parameter, it is just skipped. If you don't believe - just test it. It works fine

Comment: I'll second the works fine thing. I tried it as well.

Comment: Yep it works, but it might not in the future as it is **not documented**.

Comment: @Radek S you're confusing the SDK and the foundations of programming language. Messaging is the basis of Objective C (and it is absolutely independent from Cocoa), and it's almost certain that it's rules would not be changed in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sure it's not running when locked? I just tried it, put that scheduleTimerWithTimeInterval in the app delegate's didFinishLaunching method, locked screen on simulator, and still get the callbacks.

Comment: Strange....! It's been working now..!!! I am sure that it wasn't working before but now I am not able to reproduce the scenario. It wasn't working and hence, I was struggling around setting     
    application.idleTimerDisabled = TRUE; 
which worked for me. But now timer callback function is getting called when screen is locked. Absolutely mystery for me..!!